# skphysicsbody to skspritenode error

Tags: swift

Here is the code:

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

struct PhysicsCatagory {
    static let Player  :UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let shark :UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let jellyfish :UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var Player = SKSpriteNode()
    var game = true
    var playerPos = false
    var ScoreCount = 0
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "3D-Thirteen-Pixel-Fonts")
    var HighScore = 0
    let DisplayScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "3D-Thirteen-Pixel-Fonts")
    let LeaderBoardScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "3D-Thirteen-Pixel-Fonts")
    let LeaderBoardHighscore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "3D-Thirteen-Pixel-Fonts")
    var CheckGameState = false
    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Play")
    let Scores = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "LeaderBoard")
    var PlayerUpState = false
    var PlayerDownState = false
    var ifPlayerDrawJustCalled = false
    var TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var TextureArray = [SKTexture]()
    var TextureAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas()
    var TextureArray2 = [SKTexture]()
    var TextureAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas()
    var TextureArray3 = [SKTexture]()
    var motionManager: CMMotionManager!
    var fishYpos = 115.0
    let shark = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shark")
    let jellyfish = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jellyfish")



    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        print("called")

        motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        motionManager.startGyroUpdates()
        motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.02




         backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 7.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if(HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil){
            HighScore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! Int
        }


      TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Images")
        TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "win_1.png"))
        TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "win_2.png"))
       TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "win_3.png"))
       TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "win_4.png"))


        TextureAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Images")
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_1.png"))
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_2.png"))
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_3.png"))
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_4.png"))
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_5.png"))
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_6.png"))
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_7.png"))
        TextureArray3.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jellyfish_8.png"))


        TextureAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Images")
        TextureArray2.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark_1.png"))
        TextureArray2.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark_2.png"))
        TextureArray2.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark_3.png"))
        TextureArray2.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark_4.png"))
        TextureArray2.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark_5.png"))
        TextureArray2.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark_6.png"))




        Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: TextureAtlas.textureNames[0])



        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        Player.zPosition = 10.0




        Player.position = CGPoint(x: 80, y: fishYpos)
        Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


        myLabel.text = "\(ScoreCount)"
        myLabel.fontSize = 70
        myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), frame.size.height-150)
        myLabel.zPosition = 18.0
        addChild(myLabel)

        addChild(Player)

        Player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(TextureArray, timePerFrame: 0.20)))


        var BubbleTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self,selector: "addBubble", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        var Gyro = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.02, target:self,selector: "gyroFunction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        var MainTimer1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self,selector: "RunTimeTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        var sharkTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.70, target: self, selector: "RunSharkTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        var jellyfishTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,  target: self, selector: "RunJellyfishTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }





    func addBubble(){

        let randomNum1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

        if(randomNum1 == 2){
            let randomNum2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
            if(randomNum2 == 1){
                let Bubble1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bubble1")
                Bubble1.position.x = Player.position.x+9
                Bubble1.position.y = Player.position.y
                Bubble1.zPosition = 2.0
                addChild(Bubble1)
                Bubble1.runAction(SKAction.moveToY( frame.size.height+20, duration: 3.0))
            }
            if(randomNum2 == 0){
                let Bubble2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bubble2")
                Bubble2.position.x = Player.position.x+9
                Bubble2.position.y = Player.position.y
                Bubble2.zPosition = 3.0
                addChild(Bubble2)
                Bubble2.runAction(SKAction.moveToY( frame.size.height+20, duration: 3.0))

            }
        }
    }


    func RunTimeTimer(){
        if(game == true){
            timer()
        }
    }

    func RunSharkTimer(){
        if(game == true){
            addShark()
        }
    }

    func RunJellyfishTimer(){
        if(game == true){
            addJellyfish()
        }
    }

    func gyroFunction(){

        if let gyro_y = motionManager.gyroData?.rotationRate.y {
            if(fishYpos+gyro_y*(-10) > 115){
                if(CGFloat(fishYpos+gyro_y*(-10)) < frame.size.height-115){

                fishYpos = fishYpos+gyro_y*(-10)

                let fishAction = SKAction.moveToY(CGFloat(fishYpos), duration: 0.05)
                Player.runAction(fishAction)


                }
            }
        }
    }





    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let firstBody = contact.bodyA as! SKSpriteNode
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB as! SKSpriteNode




        if(((firstBody.name == "Player") && (secondBody.name == "shark")) || (firstBody.name == "shark") && (secondBody.name == "Player") || ((firstBody.name == "Player") && (secondBody.name == "jellyfish")) || (firstBody.name == "jellyfish") && (secondBody.name == "Player")){


        game = false
        if(CheckGameState == false){

            playButton.xScale = 1.9
            playButton.yScale = 1.9
            playButton.zPosition = 12.0
            playButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX-50, y: frame.midY-140)
            playButton.name = "playButton"
            playButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
            addChild(playButton)
            if(ScoreCount>HighScore){
                HighScore = ScoreCount
                let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                HighscoreDefault.setInteger(HighScore, forKey: "Highscore")
            }

            LeaderBoardScore.text = "\(ScoreCount)"
            LeaderBoardHighscore.text = "\(HighScore)"

            LeaderBoardHighscore.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX+30 , y: frame.midY+5)
            LeaderBoardHighscore.xScale = 2.0
            LeaderBoardHighscore.yScale = 2.0
            LeaderBoardHighscore.zPosition = 15.0
            LeaderBoardHighscore.fontColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
            LeaderBoardScore.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX+60 , y: frame.midY+72)
            LeaderBoardScore.fontColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
            LeaderBoardScore.xScale = 2.0
            LeaderBoardScore.zPosition = 15.0
            LeaderBoardScore.yScale = 2.0
            addChild(LeaderBoardHighscore)
            addChild(LeaderBoardScore)
            Scores.xScale = 2
            Scores.yScale = 2
            Scores.zPosition = 11.0
            Scores.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
            addChild(Scores)
            CheckGameState = true

            }
        }

    }




    func addShark(){

        Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.shark
        Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.shark
        Player.name = "Player"
        Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        let randomNumShark = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if(randomNumShark == 1){
            let shark = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shark_1.png")


            shark.position.x = frame.size.width
            let PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            shark.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY)
            addChild(shark)
            let sharkGoForward = SKAction.moveToX(CGFloat(-1100), duration: 1.5)
            shark.runAction(sharkGoForward)
            shark.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: shark.size.width, height:shark.size.height))
            shark.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
            shark.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
            shark.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
            shark.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            shark.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            shark.name = "shark"
            shark.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(TextureArray2, timePerFrame: 0.05)))


        }

    }

    func addJellyfish(){
            Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.jellyfish
            Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.jellyfish
            Player.name = "Player"
            Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


            let randomNumJelly = arc4random_uniform(2)
            if(randomNumJelly == 1){
                let jellyfish = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jellyfish")
                jellyfish.position.y = 0
                let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
                jellyfish.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)
                addChild(jellyfish)
                let jellyfishGoUp = SKAction.moveToY(CGFloat(frame.size.height+100), duration: 2.0)
                jellyfish.runAction(jellyfishGoUp)
                jellyfish.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: jellyfish.size.width, height:jellyfish.size.height))
                jellyfish.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
                jellyfish.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
                jellyfish.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
                jellyfish.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
                jellyfish.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                jellyfish.name = "jellyfish"
                jellyfish.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(TextureArray3, timePerFrame: 0.05)))

            }






        }











    func timer(){
        if(game == true){

            ScoreCount++
            myLabel.text = "\(ScoreCount)"
        }
    }



    func rePositionPlayer(){
        Player.removeFromParent()
        Player.position = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 220)
        addChild(Player)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


        for touch in (touches ) {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if(game == false){
                if playButton.containsPoint(location){
                    game = true
                    LeaderBoardHighscore.removeFromParent()
                    LeaderBoardScore.removeFromParent()
                    playButton.removeFromParent()
                    Scores.removeFromParent()
                    CheckGameState = false
                    rePositionPlayer()
                    ScoreCount = 0
                    fishYpos = 220
                }
            }


            if(game == true){

            }
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

My error is at the line

```
let secondbody = contact.bodyB as! SKSpriteNode
```

It says

> can cast SKPhysicsBody to unrealted SKSpriteNode

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try saying `let secondbody.node = contact.bodyB as! SKSpriteNode`